# create labels on a form taken from cells in a datagridview on another form vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, forms, datagridview, label

I have a datagridview on a form with 6 columns and an undetermined number of rows.  The user is entering values into this datagridview.  I would now like to create an invoice based on the entries in the datagridview.  I am creating this invoice on another form.  Unfortunately, the values in the cells are not showing up with the code I have.  This is the code located in the Invoice class.

```
Dim lbl(5) As Label

    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In Main.DataGridView1.Rows
        If Not row.IsNewRow Then
            Dim x As Integer = 0
            For Each col As DataGridViewColumn In Main.DataGridView1.Columns
                i = row.Index
                j = col.Index
                With lbl(x)
                    .AutoSize = True
                    .BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control
                    .Font = New Font(lbl(x).Font.FontFamily, 8.45, FontStyle.Regular)
                    .ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText
                    .Location = New System.Drawing.Point(i * 111 + 6, (i + 1) * 24 + 16)
                    .Text = Main.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value
                End With
                MsgBox(lbl(x).Text)
                GroupBoxInvoiceInvoice.Controls.Add(lbl(x))
                x += 1
            Next
        End If
    Next
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the new block of code.

```
 Dim Label1, Label2, Label3, Label4, Label5, Label6 As New Label
    Dim lbl() As Control = {Label1, Label2, Label3, Label4, Label5, Label6}
    Dim val() As String = {"Date", "Category", "Description", "Units", "Rate", "Amount"}

    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In Main.DataGridView1.Rows
        If Not row.IsNewRow And i < Main.DataGridView1.Rows.Count Then
            Dim x As Integer = 0

            For Each col As DataGridViewColumn In Main.DataGridView1.Columns
                i = row.Index
                j = col.Index
                With lbl(x)
                    .AutoSize = True
                    .BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control
                    .Font = New Font(lbl(x).Font.FontFamily, 8.45, FontStyle.Regular)
                    .ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText
                    .Location = New System.Drawing.Point(j * 111 + 6, (i + 1) * 24 + 16)
                    .Text = Main.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value
                End With
                GroupBoxInvoiceInvoice.Controls.Add(lbl(x))
                x += 1
                j += 1
            Next
            i += 1
            j = 0
            x = 0
        End If
    Next
```

Thank you, Plutonix!!  You're help has been awesome and greatly appreciated!  You have shown much patience, also!  Here is the final portion of code that worked for me based off of what you had shown below.  Thanks again!!

```
i = 0
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In Main.DataGridView1.Rows
        If Not row.IsNewRow Then

            For c As Integer = 0 To row.Cells.Count - 3
                Dim lbl As New Label
                With lbl
                    .AutoSize = True
                    .BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control
                    .Font = New Font(lbl.Font.FontFamily, 8.45, FontStyle.Regular)
                    .ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText
                    .Location = New System.Drawing.Point(c * 111 + 6, (i + 1) * 24 + 16)
                    .Text = row.Cells(c).Value.ToString
                End With
                GroupBoxInvoiceInvoice.Controls.Add(lbl)
                Console.WriteLine("label {0}", row.Cells(c).Value.ToString)
            Next
        End If
        i += 1
    Next
```

Comment: I used row.Cells.Count - 3 in the For c loop because there are cells in columns that were not being shown in the invoice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 1 or 2 problems with your loop.

```
Dim lbl(5) As Label
```

This declares you plan to make an array of labels, but you never initialize it.  When I try to run your code (w/o dgv) it crashes because there is nothing in lbl(x) ('Object reference not set to an instance of an object.').  There is no reason to stash the labels in an array if they are going to be added to a form.  So, just create labels as you need them:

```
For Each col As DataGridViewColumn In Main.DataGridView1.Columns
    i = row.Index
    j = col.Index

    Dim lbl As New Label           ' make a new label
    With lbl
         .AutoSize = True
         .BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control
         .Font = New Font(lbl(x).Font.FontFamily, 8.45, FontStyle.Regular)
         .ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText

         ' the above props are being set to default values, so arent really needed
         .Location = New System.Drawing.Point(i * 111 + 6, (i + 1) * 24 + 16)

         ' I think this needs to be changed:
          .Text = Main.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.ToString
    End With
    MsgBox(lbl(x).Text)
    GroupBoxInvoiceInvoice.Controls.Add(lbl)

    x += 1
 Next
```

This worked fine without the dgv reference, so if the labels are still blank, check to make sure there is something in those cells to display.  If that loop was executing all the way something somewhere was eating the exception and could be eating another.

-------------------- EDIT ----------------------------

The problem is using row.index and col.index as for i,j.  Those have to do with databands and return 0 otherwise.  You want to loop thru the CELLS for each row:

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgv.Rows

   If row.IsNewRow = False Then

    ' loop thru cells in row
    For c As Integer = 0 To rrow.Cells.Count - 1

        Dim lbl As New Label
        With lbl
            .AutoSize = True
            .BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control
            .BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D


            .ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText
            .Location = New System.Drawing.Point(r + 5, c * 22)    ' FIX

            ' CONVERT value TO STRING!!!
            .Text = rrow.Cells(c).Value.ToString
        End With

        Panel1.Controls.Add(lbl)
        ' prints as many time as there are labels/cells
        Console.WriteLine("label {0}", rrow.Cells(c).Value.ToString)
    Next
 End If
Next

Console.WriteLine("{0}", Panel1.Controls.Count)    ' my locations are foobar
     ' but the right number are there.
```

You will want to add r,c (or i, j) counters for positioning the labels on the form, but otherwise, all is well in LabelLand...of should be

Comment: So, I've come up with some code that does what I want it to do for one row of entries from the dgv on the Main form.  After 1 row of entries it goes to the show form routine.  I think the problem is in the for each row statement.

Comment: I am trying to create a new label for each cell.

Comment: no...for each row / for each CELL in this row not columns (delete any/all old comments or we run out of space)...`For c = 0 To row.Cells.Count` ... `lbl.Text = row.Cells(c).Value.ToString`

Comment: Okay!  I'll give that a try and let you know how it turns out!  Thank you for your help and endless patience!!

Comment: Editted example...what I meant earlier about an issue with dgv, was as a datasource or how it is referenced.